# NodeJS Out of memory, using for loop with asynchronous function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

```
exports.updateFullCentralRecordSheet = function (req, _id, type) {
  FullCentralRecordSheet.remove({_ExternalParty: _id, centralRecordType: type, centralSheetType: "Central Sheet"}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      saveErrorLog(req, err);
    }
    let query = {"structure.externalPartyRelationships": {$elemMatch: {_ExternalParty: _id}}, disabled: {$mod: [2, 0]}, initialized: true, profitLossType: type};
    let fullCentralRecordSheetObjects = [];
    ProfitLossSheet.find(query).sort({profitLossDate: 1}).lean().exec(function (err, profitLossSheetObjects) {
      if (err) {
        saveErrorLog(req, err);
      }
      async.each(profitLossSheetObjects, function (profitLossSheetObject, callback) {
          /// HEAVY COMPUTATION HERE
          callback();
        });
      }, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          saveErrorLog(req, err);
        } else {
          query = {centralRecordMode: {$in: ["Payment In", "Payment Out", "Transfer", "General Out"]}, disabled: {$mod: [2, 0]}, centralRecordType: {$in: ["Split", type]}, _ExternalParty: _id, status: {$ne: "Reject"}};
          CentralRecordSheet.find(query).lean().exec(function (err, centralRecordSheetObjects) {
            if (err) {
              saveErrorLog(req, err);
            }
            _.each(centralRecordSheetObjects, function (centralRecordSheetObject) {
               // SOME MORE PROCESSING
            });
            fullCentralRecordSheetObjects = _.sortBy(fullCentralRecordSheetObjects, function (fullCentralRecordSheetObject) {
              return new Date(fullCentralRecordSheetObject.centralRecordDate).getTime();
            });
            let runningBalance = 0;
            _.each(fullCentralRecordSheetObjects, function (fullCentralRecordSheetObject) {
              runningBalance = runningBalance - fullCentralRecordSheetObject.paymentIn.total + fullCentralRecordSheetObject.paymentOut.total + fullCentralRecordSheetObject.moneyIn.total - fullCentralRecordSheetObject.moneyOut.total + fullCentralRecordSheetObject.transferIn.total - fullCentralRecordSheetObject.transferOut.total;
              fullCentralRecordSheetObject.balance = runningBalance;
              const newFullCentralSheetRecordObject = new FullCentralRecordSheet(fullCentralRecordSheetObject);
              newFullCentralSheetRecordObject.save(); // Asynchronous save
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
};
```

This is my code to process some data and save it to database. As you can see there is some computation involves in each async loop and after the loop there is final processing of data. It works fine if I pass in one _id at a time. However when I try to do the task like this

```
exports.refreshFullCentralRecordSheetObjects = function (req, next) {
      ExternalParty.find().exec(function (err, externalPartyObjects) {
        if (err) {
          utils.saveErrorLog(req, err);
          return next(err, null, [req.__(err.message)], []);
        }
        _.each(externalPartyObjects, function (externalPartyObject) {
            updateFullCentralRecordSheet(req, externalPartyObject._id, "Malay");
            updateFullCentralRecordSheet(req, externalPartyObject._id, "Thai");
        })
        return next(err, null, ["Ddd"], ["Ddd"]);
      });
    };
```

I have about 273 objects to loop through. This cause the memory fatal error. I tried to increase `--max-old-space-size=16000` but it is still crashing. I used task manager to track the memory of node.exe process and it goes over 8 GB.

I am not sure why increasing memory to 16GB does not help, it is still crashing around 8GB (according to task manager). Another thing is when I try to only process 10 records instead of 273, task manager report that it is using about 500 MB. This 500 MB will not disappear unless I make another request to the server. I find this very odd because why isn't NodeJS garbage collect after it is done with processing 10 records? Those 10 records successfully processed and saved to database however the memory usage remain unchanged in task manager.

I tried using async.forEachLimit, turning my update function to be asynchronous, play around with process.nextTick() but I still have fatal error memory problem. What can I do to make sure this runs?

Comment: Did you try using `async.eachLimit(profitLossSheetObjects, ...` instead of `async.each(profitLossSheetObjects, ...`?

Answer (score 0):

> Another thing is when I try to only process 10 records instead of 273,
>   task manager report that it is using about 500 MB. This 500 MB will
>   not disappear unless I make another request to the server. I find this
>   very odd because why isn't NodeJS garbage collect after it is done
>   with processing 10 records? Those 10 records successfully processed
>   and saved to database however the memory usage remain unchanged in
>   task manager.

That's normal, node GC is lazy (GC is a synchronous operation, blocking the loop, so that's a good thing).

Try to paginate the query ?